# Как сделать, чтобы hint не исчезал, пока не отведете от объекта?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как сделать, чтобы hint не исчезал, пока не отведете от объекта?

Comment: Сходить на torry.net и поискать компонент для хинтов )

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы подсказка не исчезала, то просто `HintHidePause = -1`.

Answer (score 1):

очередной *кудрявый* сниппет
пример работы с подсказками:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HintColor := clGrayText;
  Application.HintPause := 250;
  Application.HintHidePause := 5000;     
end;
```

Свойство HintColor задает фон подсказок. Свойство HintPause - время до показа подсказки в миллисекундах (где 1000 - одна секунда), а свойство HintHidePause **время показа подсказки**, которое делаете over 9000 секунд, и хинт не исчезнет, пока курсор не уберете.

Comment: Но задачу он не решает ) через 5 секунд хинт пропадет, не так ли?

Comment: делаете HintHidePause over 9000 секунд, и хинт не исчезнет, пока курсор не уберете. если это задача на изматывание пользователя, то он, в принципе, может дождаться исчезновения.

ЗЫ. в тексте написано "пример", что означает, что товарищу задавшему вопрос стоит посмотреть на _пример_, и переделать его под себя, если он посчитает нужным.

Comment: хотите решения проблемы? делайте свой класс хинтов

Comment: я к тому и клоню

Comment: я клоню к тому, что задача может не требовать создания собственного класса, а можно найти компромисс в виде увеличения длительности отображения стандартного хинта ;)

Comment: Я вам не скажу за всю Калькутту, но здесь не наблюдаю ничего *кудрявого*, в отличии [от](http://hashcode.ru/answer_link/95967/) :)